# Pick up correspondent value in another data table without FOR in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, apply, lapply

I'm not very good in English, but I'l try to explain my problem

I have a Data Table (`BASE_KPM_PD`) like this with the values that I have to pick up

```
MOB PD_MONTH
1   0,000
2   0,000
3   0,000
4   0,000
5   0,003
6   0,007
7   0,006
8   0,006
9   0,004
```

And I have other Data Table (`BASE_MONTHS`) with the values for each month. The values are the same as `MOB` Column from the Data Table above

```
MONTH_1 MONTH_2 MONTH_3
1        2        3
2        3        4
3        4        5
4        5        6
5        6        7
6        7        8
7        8        9
```

I need to check the value and to pickup the `PD_MONTH` correspondent to MOB. Desired Output is below

```
PD_MONTH1   PD_MONTH2   PD_MONTH3
0,000         0,000       0,000
0,000         0,000       0,000
0,000         0,000       0,003
0,000         0,003       0,007
0,003         0,007       0,006
0,007         0,006       0,006
0,006         0,006       0,004
```

The code that I have tried was. This code works, but it isn't the best or fast code:

```
BASE_PD <- BASE_MONTHS 
      for (j in 1:3){
         BASE_PD <- merge(BASE_PD,
                         BASE_KPM_PD[,c("MOB","PD_MONTH")],
                         by.x = colnames(BASE_PD[paste0("MONTH_",j)]),
                         by.y = "MOB" )
        drops <- c(paste0("MONTH_",j))
        BASE_PD <- BASE_PD[,!names(BASE_PD) %in% drops]
        colnames(BASE_PD)[length(BASE_PD)] <- paste0("PD_MONTH_",j)
      }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post code showing what methods you have tried that did not work. You need to demonstrate code that you have tried that is not working rather than asking users to write code for you.

Comment: I edited above and posted the code I've tried. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data set `BASE_KPM_PD`, you appear to have index column "MOB" and data column "PD_MONTH". As long as those indices are kept in the correct order (1-12, with no gaps), the following should work.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(BASE_MONTHS, function(x) BASE_KPM_PD$PD_MONTH[x]))
```

This goes through every column of `BASE_MONTHS` and uses its values as an index to `BASE_KPM_PD`.